# Actionscript 2.0, measure a functions execution time?

Tags: performance, flash, actionscript

How can i measure the time it takes to execute a function in ActionScript 2.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var beforeTime = getTimer();
yourFunction();
var afterTime = getTimer();
var measure = afterTime - beforeTime;
```